# Getting path of the top-level Python script

Tags: python

I want to get the path of invoked (top-level) Python script. Actually it is a package and I am running it with `python3 -m <package-name>`. I researched web and Stack Overflow but couldn't find a proper solution. `__file__` and `__path__` are not working, `os.getcwd()` doesn't work if the package is invoked from another location, `sys.argv[0]` is not guaranteed to have the full path. The way `import __main__` is not a good way I think since I import the top-level script into a dependent script.

Comment: You're probably trying to do something that you shouldn't be doing. A package is supposed to implement an API, and not care by whom it is used, or through how many intermediate layers. If it is used interactively, there isn't even a top-level Python script. If you could explain what you're trying to do with the information about the top-level script, somebody might suggest an alternative way to accomplish that.

Comment: Can’t you use `__file__` on the package, even if not on the “script”?

Comment: @RolandWeber, I am doing a Tkinter app and using `__path__` information to find absolute path of my image files. Are relative paths better? Can they be used?

Comment: @DavisHerring, I find `__path__` more useful since I don't need any splitting process to have the path. What are the differences between them other than representing file and directory path, respectively.

Comment: @ismailarilik: `__path__` is for guiding the interpreter to your modules and thus may be customized.  `__file__` is its information for you.

Comment: @ismailarilik Could you let the app set an environment variable or call a Python method in your module to tell the code where the image files are?

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the problem of open("xyz.dat","r") not finding xyz.dat in the same folder as the .py file

Solved my problem by adding "working_dir": "$file_path" to my Sublime Text 3 build script.

However, I wondered how python libraries did it.  For example, Kivy's AsyncImage has a "source" parameter to its constructor that successfully finds image files in the same folder as the top-level py file.

After some digging, I discovered the method that Kivy uses:

> import kivy.resources as kr
>
> full_path = kr.resource_find("image.png")

I do not like to rely on a setting in a build script to find files in the same folder, so this is the method I'm going to follow in future Kivy projects.

BTW, resource_find does rely on sys.argv[0] to "know" the full path of the top-level python script.

Comment: I need a general way.